# Why does %appdata% point to the appdata folder of the administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, appdata

There's a Windows 10 computer on my network where `%appdata%` points to the `%UserProfile%\AppData` folder of the built-in Administrator.

I log in as user X on the machine (X is not the built-in Administrator), click the Start Menu, type `%appdata%` followed by Enter, so I expect to be shown `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming` in an Explorer window; instead, Explorer opens to `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming`.

Why is this, and how can I correct this?

Edit: as requested by Ramhound, here are the values for:

> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell
>   Folders

[image]

Comment: Check the environment variables for that user [Click start, begin to type 'envi… & it should find it

Comment: @Tetsujin I've checked the environment variables for that user (and other users, even on other machines) - none of them have an environment variable called %appdata%.

Comment: I see someone edited my post - thanks for the improvement, but I just want to explicitly point out that %appdata% in fact points to %userprofile%\AppData on this machine, and NOT %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming!

Comment: @Joe I thought that was a mistype, as `%AppData%` should always point to `..\AppData\Roaming` and `%LocalAppData%` to `..\AppData\Local` _(in general, as you're obviously experiencing abnormal behavior)_, which is why I thought it was a mistype.

Comment: @JW0914 A logical assumption indeed, which is why I added the comment after I made the change to your (otherwise better readable) edit. Thanks!

Comment: `%UserProfile%` is defined within `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`, what I am trying to determine is, what Windows thinks the username is for the profile you are asking about.  You will have to identify the username by its SID (i.e. `S-1-5-21-xxxx`).